# Django - Foreign key constraint fails on delete with through model

Tags: mysql, django

I am working on a REST api using Django Rest and one endpoint involves deleting a Contact model, which can have multiple Addresses associated with it via ContactAddress through model.

The Contact model looks like this:

```
class Contact(AuditModel):
    contact_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    address = models.ManyToManyField('Address', through='ContactAddress')
    name_first = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name_last = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

ContactAddress looks like this:

```
class ContactAddress(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey('Contact', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_billing = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)
    is_shipping = models.BooleanField(null=True, default=False)
```

And the Address model looks like this:

```
class Address(AuditModel):
    address_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    street_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    street_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    street_line_3 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
```

And when trying to delete the contact like so with `contact.delete()` I get the following MySQL error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1451, 'Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mnghub`.`contact_addresses`, CONSTRAINT `contact_addresses_contact_id_cadc11a0_fk_contacts_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `contacts` (`contact_id`))')
```

I get this error despite the contact having no addresses associated with it. I assume the constraint is because the relationship is many-to-many, but I want to be able to delete related models if they are only related with one object

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are getting this error if the given contact has at least one associated address. Foreign keys don't block deletion of parent records that do not have child records.

Comment: The contact has no addresses or contact addresses associated with it, but I still get the error. I ran this in the shell:

`>>> contact.address.all()`
`<QuerySet []>`
`>>> contact.contactaddress_set.all()`
`<QuerySet []>`
`>>> contact.delete()`
`Traceback (most recent call last):`

```